# How to solve this nonlinear ODE? [Imposing that $f>0$]

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve an ODE of the following form
$$\frac{f'(r)}{\sqrt{1+r^2 f'(r)^2}} = a'r^3 + b'r^2+c'$$
for some constants $a'=8/60,b'=-1/4,c'=-1/2$ and $r>0$ and $f(r)\in [0,\pi]$ for all $r>0.$ I would like to impose that $f>0$ however I am not sure how to impose this constraint and solve the above ODE in Mathematica.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you mean by  **would like to impose that f>0**

The solution to the ode is whatever the solution comes out.

You could always filter out the ones you do not want. However in this ode, the two solutions can not be integrated anyway, so not possible to obtain an explicit $f(r)$ to check if it is always positive or not over the range you have, since can not plot it for example, or do any other analysis on the solution to check.

```
a = 8/60; b = -1/4; c = -1/2;
ode = f'[r]/Sqrt[1 + r^2*f'[r]^2] == a*r^3 + b*r^2 + c
DSolve[ode, f[r],r]
```

[image: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoSQ0.png)]

Since this ode is just quadrature. So solve for $f'[r]$ and integrate the root you want.

```
deps = f'[r] /. Solve[ode, f'[r]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution(s) $f(r)$ to the ode are just the integrals of these

```
sol1 = Integrate[First@deps,r] +C[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol2 = Integrate[Last@deps,r] + C[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the same as Mathematica gives of course.

You can see, it is not possible to integrate these.

So to answer your question. You can't impose this condition on `DSolve` but you can always filter the solution you want. In this case, since it can't integrate it, you can't even obtain an explicit solution to check.

You can ofcourse numerically integrate this from zero to Pi, but this does not tell if $f(r)$ is always positive or not.

Btw, if you had given an initial condition, then Mathematica `NDSolve` can solve it. This gives the two solutions. One is always positive over the range and the second is always negative.

```
sol = NDSolve[{ode, f[0] == 0}, f, {r, 0, Pi}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[r] /. sol], {r, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]